# I am having trouble generating command regarding following json file I have

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv, data-analysis

This is how my json file looks

```
   "Patient":{
      "Name":{
         "Patient First Name":"James",
         "Patient Middle Name":"Adam",
         "Patient Last Name":"Manchester"
      },
      "Unique ID":163983,
      "Demographics":{
         "Sex":"M",
         "Birthdate":"7/24/1940"
      },
      "IntakeCriteria":{
         "DmDxDate":"8/25/2012",
         "InitialHgbA1c":8.1,
         "Comorbidity":["Diabetes Mellitus","CHF","DVT"]
      },
      "Labs":{
         "LDLCholesterol":{
            "LDLResultDate":"5/6/2013",
            "LDLLevel":200
         },
         "SerumCreatinine":{
            "CreatinineResultDate":"11/1/2016",
            "CreatinineLevel":0.9
         }
      },
      "CareLocation":{
         "Facility Name":"East Side Clinic",
         "Facility Contact Name":"Mary Silverman",
         "Facility Contact Phone":"618-348-1891"
      }
   }
}
```

I need to prepare a query using the following fields:

```
Patient Unique ID number.
Patient First Name.
Patient Last Name.
Lab Test Date.
HgbA1c Level.
LDL Level.
Creatinine Level.
```

I tried this resulting in no result

```
jq - r’[.Patient.UniqueID, .Patient.Name.FirstName, .Patient.Name.LastName, .Patient.Labs.LDLCholesterol.LabResultDate, .Patient.IntakeCriteria.InitialHgbA1c, .Patient.Labs.LDLCholesterol.LDLLevel, .Patient.Labs.SerumCreatine.CreatineLevel] | @csv’ data.json > csvtest.out
```

Answer (score 0):

When using [object identifiers](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectIdentifier-Index%3A.foo%2C.foo.bar), you have to provide the field names exactly as used in the JSON file. Also, if they contain special characters such as white spaces (or start with a digit), surround them with double quotes for clarification:

```bash
jq -r '[
  .Patient."Unique ID",
  .Patient.Name."Patient First Name",
  .Patient.Name."Patient Last Name",
  .Patient.Labs.LDLCholesterol.LDLResultDate,
  .Patient.IntakeCriteria.InitialHgbA1c,
  .Patient.Labs.LDLCholesterol.LDLLevel,
  .Patient.Labs.SerumCreatinine.CreatinineLevel
] | @csv' data.json > csvtest.out
```

```json
163983,"James","Manchester","5/6/2013",8.1,200,0.9
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/z_FInach6LA)

To shorten your filter a bit, you may also group together some of the paths sharing common parents using [subfilters with pipes](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Pipe%3A%7C) `|` within a [grouping with parentheses](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Parenthesis) `()`:

```bash
jq -r '[.Patient |
  ."Unique ID",
  (.Name | ."Patient First Name", ."Patient Last Name"),
  .Labs.LDLCholesterol.LDLResultDate,
  .IntakeCriteria.InitialHgbA1c,
  (.Labs | .LDLCholesterol.LDLLevel, .SerumCreatinine.CreatinineLevel)
] | @csv' data.json > csvtest.out
```

```json
163983,"James","Manchester","5/6/2013",8.1,200,0.9
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/k07ywUeh2Dm)